# How to create dynamic SQL queries inside CURSOR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to dynamically create a query inside `cursor`

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(10)

declare @loc varchar(25)
set @loc = '/MainItem/SubItem';

declare @query varchar(max)     

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT * FROM @tempcolumnname

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    set @query = 'SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '+@loc+', 3) WITH (code_db_key int)'
    exec (@query)    

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id
END
```

but executing this throws an exception

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@hdoc"
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>
> If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause
>   or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement
>   must be terminated with a semicolon.`

But when I am executing the same query outside the cursor, it is working fine.

Comment: Cannot find where '@hdoc' is defined.

Comment: hdoc is declared at the start of the procedure. Its not shown here but is present

Comment: outside the cursor it is working fine.

Comment: Asking just to confirm : Does "Dynamic SQL" work outside cursor and not just the normal SQL statement ?

Comment: Have you added `PRINT @querry` just before the `EXEC` to make sure that the dynamic SQL is really what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cursor you have to again execute your xml file , with xml output declaration.

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(25)

declare @loc varchar(25)
set @loc = '/MainItem/SubItem';

declare @query varchar(max) 

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
     SELECT * FROM @tempcolumnname

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    set @query = 'DECLARE @hdoc INT;           
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT,'''+ @info+'''
        Select Statement
        Insert Statement exec (@query)      

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id       
END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
set @query = 'SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '+@loc+', 3) WITH (code_db_key int)'
```

to

```
set @query = 'SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '+@loc+', 3) WITH (code_db_key int);'
```

--

Ok, try this,

```
set @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc,',+@loc+,', 3) WITH (code_db_key int);')
```

Comment: Im trying different things atm.

Comment: And like Ravi says, there is no declare for @hdoc

Comment: There is also no declare for  @tempcolumnname

Comment: now its throwing other exception `Msg 102, Level 15, State 3,  Line 171
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: all declare statement are there at the start of procedure . Its a long procedure so I have not copied everything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29468/discussion-between-veer-b-singh-and-kay-nelson)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

/* Build the SQL string one time.*/
set @query = 
'SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@Temphdoc, '''+@loc+''', 3) WITH (code_db_key int)';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@Temphdoc varchar(1000)';

/* This can be in cursor loop */

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, @ParmDefinition,
                      @Temphdoc = @hdoc;
```