# How do I use a table name that's returned in a select statement, in a join?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic

*Note: This is not the same as the "possible duplicate".  Here, the table name will be different for each record returned in the SELECT statement. So I can't just "set" a variable like `set @tableName = 'whatever'`.

Here's my SQL - take a look at my last inner join.  e.Name from the table EmailSendDefintion is the name of the table I need to join to.  So, this is kind of dynamic, I know, but how do I join to a table that is stored in a field in another table?

```
    select top 5000 
    x.HL_ACCT_ID as 'HL_ACCT_ID',
    x.SALE_CODE as 'SALE_CODE', 
    s.SubscriberKey as 'EmailAddress',
    o.EventDate as 'Opened',
    c.EventDate as 'Clicked',
    b.EventDate as 'Bounced'
    from c100._sent s with (nolock)
    inner join c100._job j with (nolock) on s.jobid = j.jobid
    inner join emailsenddefinition e with (nolock) on e.customerkey = j.emailsenddefinition
    left join c100._open o with (nolock) on o.jobid = s.jobid and o.subscriberkey = s.subscriberkey
    left join c100._click c with (nolock) on c.jobid = s.jobid and c.subscriberkey = s.subscriberkey
    left join c100._bounce b with (nolock) on b.jobid = s.jobid and b.subscriberkey = s.subscriberkey
inner join c100.[e.name] x with (nolock) on x.EmailAddress = s.SubscriberKey
    where e.clientid = 100
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic SQL queries inside CURSOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394720/how-to-create-dynamic-sql-queries-inside-cursor)

Comment: I'm seconding @Juan.  What you want seems like a dynamic sql to fill up an sql command array and then executing it itteratively.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could just create a view that outputs the `union` of all the `e.name` tables? Then join to the view.

In order to keep this short, let's say you have just 2 different tables whose name could be in the `e.name` column, `SubscriberEmail1` and `SubscriberEmail2`.

Then you could create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW SubscriberEmailUnion
AS
    SELECT 
        'SubscriberEmail1' as TableName,
        HL_ACCT_ID,
        SALE_CODE,
        EmailAddress
    FROM SubscriberEmail1

    UNION

    SELECT 
        'SubscriberEmail2' as TableName,
        HL_ACCT_ID,
        SALE_CODE,
        EmailAddress
    FROM SubscriberEmail2
GO
```

Note that each *part* of the view is adding the name of it's underlying table as a column. You can then change your final join to:

```
inner join SubscriberEmailUnion x with (nolock) on (
    x.EmailAddress = s.SubscriberKey
    AND x.TableName = e.Name
)
```

I'm personally most familiar with `MS Sql Server` so my sample uses that syntax. Should be easy enough to change to work with a different server if necessary though.

For performance you can then use whatever feature your DB has, indexed views etc.

Answer (score 0):

How many tables do you have? If not too many one option would be to left join all of them

```
left join c100.table1 x1 on x1.EmailAddress = s.SubscriberKey and [e.name] = 'table1'
left join c100.table2 x1 on x2.EmailAddress = s.SubscriberKey and [e.name] = 'table2'
etc...
```

and then in the select

```
coalesce(x1.HL_ACCT_ID, x2.HL_ACCT_ID, etc...) as 'HL_ACCT_ID',
```